# Let's say I visit a website that installs malware on my computer, how bad can the malware be, and how can I know that it is there?

Tags: web-browser, virus, websites

Ok, I'm a bit paranoid about malware and hacking, and I already know that visiting websites can give you malware without you knowing, so I was just wondering, how can I know if I have this type of malware, how bad can it be, and how can I remove it?

Answer (score 2):

> How bad can the malware be, how can I know that it is there, and how can I remove it?

As bad as any malware can be, where it comes from or how it gets onto your computer doesn't make a difference.

Not all malware is created equal, but for the stuff that's well-written: you can't (unless you get lucky with a virus scanner or know what to look for), and you can't (unless you get lucky with a virus scanner or know what to look for).

Like anything with security, an ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure: use script blockers, virus scanners, keep backups on unplugged hard drives, etc because once malware gets into your computer undetectod, you're usually toast.

Comment: Detecting malware is a fun niche field, and there are plenty of ways to do so. I wouln't say "can't" for the last one.

Comment: @MarkBuffalo Fair :P I'm making an assumption about the skill level of the OP since an expert at treating malware probably wouldn't ask this question.